# CSRF Test are failed in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, antiforgerytoken

I have completed an ASP.NET MVC application and at the end we are going through a security test. I have passed all the tests except two. One is CSRF. In my application I have put `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on every form to be submitted to the server and the respective action method is decorated with a `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. After an exercise, I think I am correct since most of internet suggests to do what I am actually doing, but the testing team is saying that CSRF has failed. Now, they are putting forward a remark that value in cookie is not changed on every request, but that it changes on the form page.

*I am not sure why the value is changing in page but not in cookie?*

Comment: AntiForgeryToken/ValidateAntiForgeryToken is indeed the correct way to protect against CSRF. That the cookie value doesn't change doesn't mean that the application is vulnerable to CSRF. Have the security testers provided a proof of concept? Do you have more information?

Comment: They have given me a snapshot of crafted html and it is only posting when user user is authenticated. They are asking me that request token in cookie which is same for whole session but token in the page changes on every request. Conceptually, If I am correct both of them shall be same, so I am also skeptical to the issue